# Verify that the function $f(x) \geq g(x)$, where $f(x) = \cos (x)$ and $g(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am verifying whether the function $f(x) \geq g(x)$, where  $f(x) = \cos (x)$ and $g(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Also I am checking whether $f(x) - g(x)$ changes sign in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2) $ or not?

**My attempt:** Since $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$. Now integrating this inequality two times between 0 to $x$ proves desired result for all $x$. Thus $f(x) - g(x)$ will never changes sign as its positive function. Am I on the right path? I asked this question because I want to explore alternative approaches for solving it if  my current method is correct.

Thank you so much for your assistance

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for your response. I am sorry I am not clear about your comment.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct.

My proof:

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=cosx+\frac{x^2}{2}-1$, then $h'(x)=-sinx+x, h''(x)=-cosx+1\geq 0$.

So $h'(x)$ is increasing, then $h'(x)$ has exactly one zero, and we can easily find that it has a zero at $x=0$ since $h'(0)=0$.

Obviously mentioned that when $x<0, h'(x)<0$; when $x>0, h'(x)>0$,

then we knows that $h(x)$ has its minimal value (also the minimum value) at $x=0$ since $h(0)=0$.

Then $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)\geq h(0)=0$. Done!

Comment: Thanks for the answer